# Multiline strings in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net

Is there a way to have multiline strings in VB.NET like Python

```
a = """
multi
line
string
"""
```

or PHP?

```
$a = <<<END
multi
line
string
END;
```

Of course something that is not

```
"multi" & _
"line
```

Comment: BTW: '"multi" & _ <newline> "line"' is _one_ string literal, not two.  It's still ugly, though.

Comment: For C#, refer [Code: Generating Multiline String Literals (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287596(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: My two cents: in VS 2017 your VB.NET code would be compiled.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You can use **[XML Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx)** to achieve a similar effect:

```
Imports System.XML
Imports System.XML.Linq
Imports System.Core

Dim s As String = <a>Hello
World</a>.Value
```

Remember that if you have special characters, you should use a CDATA block:

```
Dim s As String = <![CDATA[Hello
World & Space]]>.Value
```

---

### 2015 UPDATE:

Multi-line string literals were introduced in **Visual Basic 14** (in **Visual Studio 2015**). The above example can be now written as:

```vb
Dim s As String = "Hello
World & Space"
```

<s>`MSDN article isn't updated yet (as of 2015-08-01), so check some answers below for details.`</s>

Details are added to the [Roslyn *New-Language-Features-in-VB-14*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-VB-14#multiline-string-literals) Github repository.

Comment: how can you do variable replacements in there? like " a=" & someint & ","

Comment: @Christopher - I typically find it more readable to put tokens in the string constant, and then replace them. So `s="... a=~someint~ ..."` and then `s=s.Replace("~someint~', SomeInt)`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with dynamic compilation: CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic").CompileAssemblyFromFile(<options>, <.vb file with above trick syntax in it>) ... Any ideas?  Is this just VS 2010 syntactic sugar?

Comment: Amazing. It works with adding variables with <%=var>, without having to do all that ampersand nonsense.

Comment: Don't forget you'll have to escape your `<` characters with the fairly unreadable `&lt;` unless you're willing to also [add a CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11954808/33080) (but then you can't embed stuff using<%= %>).

Comment: @romkyns Not true, I figured out how to use CDATA and still be able to embed using <%= %>
See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net/24087600#24087600)

Comment: Brilliant. In my scenario I had to use .ToString() instead of .value to get the html code (my string contained html tags)

Comment: It seems that the enhanced Intellisense of **Resharper** doesn't like the new syntax. It compiles fine, but I get ugly red highlighting and underlining :(

Comment: Awesome!  How do you maintain code indentation without introducing it into the literal under the newer syntax?

Comment: in case anyone else has the same issue - Roslyn apparently isn't enabled for Web Site project types in VS2015 and must be downloaded separately. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

Answer (score 52):

VB.Net has no such feature and it will **not** be coming in Visual Studio 2010.  The feature that jirwin is refering is called implicit line continuation.  It has to do with removing the _ from a multi-line statement or expression.  This does remove the need to terminate a multiline string with _ but there is still no mult-line string literal in VB.

Example for multiline string

Visual Studio 2008

```
Dim x = "line1" & vbCrlf & _
        "line2"
```

Visual Studio 2010

```
Dim x = "line1" & vbCrlf & 
        "line2"
```

Comment: So then how does it work for XML literals?  Either it is possible, or XML literals are using a different technique - and if a different technique, then one that could be extended to multi-line strings.

Comment: @mellamokb XML literals are .. special for lack of a better word.  The compiler understands them and hence will allow them to span multiple lines implicitly.  No such support was added for multi-line strings.  Adding such support is *much* easier than XML literals, it just didn't meet the bar for that release.

Answer (score 44):

I used this variant:

```
     Dim query As String = <![CDATA[
        SELECT 
            a.QuestionID
        FROM 
            CR_Answers a

        INNER JOIN 
            CR_Class c ON c.ClassID = a.ClassID
        INNER JOIN
            CR_Questions q ON q.QuestionID = a.QuestionID
        WHERE 
            a.CourseID = 1
        AND 
            c.ActionPlan = 1
        AND q.Q_Year = '11/12'
        AND q.Q_Term <= (SELECT CurrentTerm FROM CR_Current_Term)
    ]]>.Value()
```

it allows < > in the string

Comment: Great technique, but one may have to add some references to your project to make it work.  See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531455%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28654126/3175562

Answer (score 42):

#### Multi-line strings are available since the Visual Studio 2015.

```vb
Dim sql As String = "
    SELECT ID, Description
    FROM inventory
    ORDER BY DateAdded
"
```

You can combine them with **string interpolation** to maximize usefullness:

```
Dim primaryKey As String = "ID"
Dim inventoryTable As String = "inventory"

Dim sql As String = $"
    SELECT {primaryKey}, Description
    FROM {inventoryTable}
    ORDER BY DateAdded
"
```

Note that interpolated strings begin with `$` and you need to take care of `"`, `{` and `}` contained inside – convert them into `""`, `{{` or `}}` respectively.

Here you can see actual **syntax highlighting** of interpolated parts of the above code example:

[image]

If you wonder if their recognition by the Visual Studio editor also works with refactoring (e.g. mass-renaming the variables), then you are right, **code refactoring works with these.** Not mentioning that they also support IntelliSense, reference counting or code analysis.

Answer (score 22):

Multiline string literals are introduced in Visual Basic 14.0 -  https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/571884

You can use then in the VS2015 Preview, out now - http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs (note that you can still use VS2015 even when targeting an older version of the .NET framework)

```
Dim multiline = "multi
line
string"
```

VB strings are basically now the same as C# verbatim strings - they don't support backslash escape sequences like \n, and they do allow newlines within the string, and you escape the quote symbol with double-quotes ""

Comment: Thank you Lucian for adding multi-line strings into the VB. Maybe you can update your answer, because VS 2015 is now RTM. And maybe you can also poke somebody in your company to update related [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5chcthbw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 16):

this was a really helpful article for me, but nobody mentioned how to **concatenate** in case you want to send some variables, which is what you need to do 99% of the time.

... **<%=** variable **%>** ...

Here's how you do it:

`<SQL>
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE FirstName='<%= EnteredName %>'
</SQL>.Value`

Comment: In this case, you want to avoid concatenation and instead use SQL parameters as they're better at hardening against SQL injection attacks. I can see this being useful for dynamic SQL generation, though (without passing along user input).

Answer (score 10):

Well, since you seem to be up on your python, may I suggest that you copy your text into python, like:

```
 s="""this is gonna 
last quite a 
few lines"""
```

then do a:

```
  for i in s.split('\n'):
    print 'mySB.AppendLine("%s")' % i

#    mySB.AppendLine("this is gonna")
#    mySB.AppendLine("last quite a")
#    mySB.AppendLine("few lines")
```

or

```
  print ' & _ \n'.join(map(lambda s: '"%s"' % s, s.split('\n')))

#    "this is gonna" & _ 
#    "last quite a" & _ 
#    "few lines"
```

then at least you can copy that out and put it in your VB code.  Bonus points if you bind a hotkey
(fastest to get with:[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)) to do this for for whatever is in your paste buffer.  The same idea works well for a SQL formatter.

Answer (score 9):

Multi-line string literals in vb.net using the XElement class.

```
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Public Sub Test()

dim sOderBy as string = ""

dim xe as XElement = <SQL>
                SELECT * FROM <%= sTableName %>
                 <ORDER_BY> ORDER BY <%= sOrderBy %></ORDER_BY>
                 </SQL>

'** conditionally remove a section 
if sOrderBy.Length = 0 then xe.<ORDER BY>.Remove

'** convert XElement value to a string 
dim sSQL as String = xe.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

To me that is the most annoying thing about VB as a language.
Seriously, i once wrote the string in a file and wrote code something along the lines of:

```
Dim s as String = file_get_contents("filename.txt")
```

just so i could test the query directly on SQL server if i need to.

My current method is to use a stored procedure on the SQL Server and just call that so i can pass in parameters to the query, etc

Comment: Maybe is a good idea to include in the project that with a .sql file extension (if Stored Procedures) are not introduced yet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860260/how-to-add-an-sql-file-to-resources-in-visual-studio#:~:text=Right%2Dclick%20your%20project%20in,Action%22%20to%20%22Embedded%20Resource%22

Answer (score 5):

I figured out how to use both <![CDATA[ along with <%= for variables, which allows you to code without worry.

You basically have to terminate the CDATA tags before the VB variable and then re-add it after so the CDATA does not capture the VB code.  You need to wrap the entire code block in a tag because you will you have multiple CDATA blocks.

```
Dim script As String = <code><![CDATA[
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var URL = ']]><%= domain %><![CDATA[/mypage.html';
  </script>]]>
</code>.value
```

Answer (score 3):

You could (should?) put the string in a resource-file (e.g. "My Project"/Resources) and then get it with

```
 Dim a = My.Resources.Whatever_you_chose
```

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I love python. It's multi-line strings are only one reason.

But I also do VB.Net, so here's my short-cut for more readable long strings.

```
  Dim lines As String() = {
    "Line 1",
    "Line 2",
    "Line 3"
  }
  Dim s As String = Join(lines, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: You need _ at the end of line for each "Line.." that looks ugly.

Comment: Actually you don't.  Later versions of VB (2010 and later I think?) don't require a _ in a lot of cases, including the example shown here.

Answer (score 2):

you can use XML for this like

```
dim vrstr as string = <s>
    some words
    some words
    some
    words
</s>
```

Answer (score 1):

in Visual studio 2010 (VB NET)i try the following and works fine

```
Dim HtmlSample As String = <anything>what ever you want to type here with multiline strings</anything>

dim Test1 as string =<a>onother multiline example</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Available in Visual Basic 14 as part of Visual Studio 2015
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890368.aspx

But not yet supported by R#. The good news is they will be supported soon! Please vote on [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-442744) to notify JetBrains you need them also.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an XML literal in VB.Net with an line code variable, this is how you would do it:

```
<Tag><%= New XCData(T.Property) %></Tag>
```

Comment: Note sure why you are mentioning an XML literal here, don't see XML mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a readability issue, I have used the following code:

```
MySql = ""
MySql = MySql & "SELECT myTable.id"
MySql = MySql & " FROM myTable"
MySql = MySql & " WHERE myTable.id_equipment = " & lblId.Text
```

Comment: This is bad. You just created 4 instances of string

Comment: I inherited a legacy VB6 code I have to port to VB.NET which is full of these! :(
In this case I prefer to sacrifice performance to maintain readability.

Comment: You don't have to. You always can concatenate without re-assigning a variable, and format within those lines

Comment: In my case is not applicable to switch to the correct syntax as I should modify a full bunch of code and there is no time left on the project.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `System.Text.StringBuilder` class in this way:

```
Dim sValue As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sValue.AppendLine("1st Line")
sValue.AppendLine("2nd Line")
sValue.AppendLine("3rd Line")
```

Then you get the multiline string using:

```
sValue.ToString()
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `vbCrLf` or `vbNewLine`. It works with MessageBoxes and many other controls I tested.

```
Dim str As String
str = "First line" & vbCrLf & "Second line"
MsgBox(str)
str = "First line" & vbNewLine & "Second line"
MsgBox(str)
```

It will show two identical MessageBoxes with 2 lines.

Answer (score -9):

No, VB.NET does not yet have such a feature. It will be available in the next iteration of VB (visual basic 10) however ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2009/03/27/channel-9-interview-no-more-underscores-in-visual-basic-10-beth-massi-tyler-whitney.aspx))

Comment: You sure? I know they're gonna allow multiline statements, but are they gonna allow multiline *strings* too? I mean "hello <newline> world"?

Comment: Removal of line continuation character and multi-line literal strings are different features.

Answer (score -16):

if it's like C# (I don't have VB.Net installed) you can prefix a string with @

```
foo = @"Multiline
String"
```

this is also useful for things like @"C:\Windows\System32\" - it essentially turns off escaping and turns on multiline.