# Multiline string literal in vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiline strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net)

How do you specify a multiple line string literal in Visual Basic .NET?

You can do it in C#:
[Multiline String Literal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

This is not supported in VB.Net.  The most common way is to do the following

```
Dim text = "First Line" & vbCrLf & _
  "Second Line" & vbCrLf & _
  "Third Line"
```