# Any online tool for converting sql statements to string format?

Tags: sql, string, format

I'm looking for a simple tool for sql formatting. 
For example:

```
SELECT 
    Something
FROM
    Sometable
```

is going to be converted as (for vb):

```
MyVar = "SELECT " & _
    "Something " & _
    "FROM " & _
    "Sometable "
```

Does anyone know any online tool for this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

If you're simply looking for a solution to convert a multi-line query to VB.NET's string format, this solution doesn't need to be specific to SQL.

You could use a VS Macro, [such as this one](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/12?n=vs-macro-for-pasting-long-text-as-string), for converting the string to VB.NET format, and adding the appropriate `& _` characters.

If you're looking for an online tool, [this page converts C# code to VB.NET code](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).  If you simply enter a string in C# format, such as:

```
@"SELECT 
    Something
FROM
    Sometable"
```

The tool will create the following VB.NET string:

```
"SELECT " & vbCr & vbLf & "    Something" & vbCr & vbLf & "FROM" & vbCr & vbLf & "    Sometable"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actualy I like to see the entire sql query without scrollbars in the code area. That's why I want a conversion line by line. It is too long when it is a single line.

Answer (score 2):

XML Literals work awesomely if you just want to include the query exactly in your code:

```
Dim s As String = <a><![CDATA[
  SELECT 
      Something
  FROM
      Sometable
]]></a>.Value
```

I found this method by searching for a way to do multiline strings in vb. The best answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674434/1865209).

Answer (score 0):

SQLinForm at www.sqlinform.com has a feature to generate P-Code out of SQL statements and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Not online, but free and simple for those using VBA: [a simple Access form](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-71.html) just for that purpose, from the excellent and always reliable Allen Browne.

Comment: @Drew: I don't get the question, the link is provided. Missing something ?

Comment: thx, user error (me)

Comment: no prob, it's friday ;-)