# Does VB.NET have a multi-line string declaration syntax equivalent to c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiline strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net)

In c#, you can be all like:

```
string s = @"hello
there
mister";
```

Does VB.NET have something similar that doesn't involve string concatenation?  I'd like to be able to paste multi-line text in between two double quotes.  Somehow, I don't believe VB.NET supports this.

Comment: [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx#Y0)

Comment: In VB.NET 14 you can now do [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx) - So:
`dim multiline = $"Multiliine
String!"`

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien You actually don't even need interpolation for that in the new VB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT: VS2015 ONWARDS**

**YOU CAN NOW HAVE MULTILINE STRINGS IN VS2015 BY WRITING THEM LIKE SO:**

```
Dim text as String = "
This
Is
Multiline
Text!"
```

There is no multi-line string literal in VB .NET - the closest thing you can get (without using LINQ) is a multi-line statement with concatenation.

Prior to VS2010:

```
Dim x = "some string" & vbCrlf & _
        "the rest of the string"
```

Post 2010:

```
Dim x = "some string" & vbCrlf &
        "the rest of the string"
```

The XML/LINQ trick is:

```
Imports System.Core
Imports System.XML
Imports System.XML.Linq

Dim x As String = <a>Some code
and stuff</a>.Value
```

But this limits what characters you can place inside the `<a></a>` block because of XML semantics. If you need to use special characters wrap the text in a standard `CDATA` block:

```
Dim x As String = <a><![CDATA[Some code
& stuff]]></a>.Value
```

Comment: I believe String Interpolation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx works for multiline

Comment: Could you update this answer now that VB.NET 14 supports multiline literals:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn890368.aspx

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can use a xml trick like this:

```
Dim s As String = <a>hello
there
mister</a>.Value
```

or put your string in a project resource.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if it's the best way of doing this but I don't think there's an equivalent operator.

```
Dim myString As String =
"Hello" & Environment.NewLine & "there" & Environment.NewLine & "mister"
```

I think the `Environement.NewLine` takes the correct line feed, depending on the OS.

EDIT: I've just read that you want to insert text multiline directly in the code, so there's another possible solution:

You have to use string quotations still, and commas, but here it is

```
    Dim myList as new List(of String) (new String(){
        "Hello",
        "there",
        "mister"
    })

    Dim result as String

    For Each bob as String In myList
        result += bob & Environment.NewLine
    next
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution still doesn't satisfy my initial request of `I'd like to be able to paste multi-line text in between two double quotes`.  To bring this string array together again, I would still have to rely on concatenation in some form, be it joining the array at `VbCrLf` or using `&=` in a loop.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what MSDN recommends
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5chcthbw(v=vs.80).aspx

MyString = "This is the first line of my string." & VbCrLf & _
           "This is the second line of my string." & VbCrLf & _
           "This is the third line of my string."