# vb .net CDATA for storing SQL multiline string, mixing with VB variables

Tags: vb.net, xml-literals

I'm using CDATA to store all multiline SQL string "as is" (thanks some stackoverflow old answer) like this:

```
Dim cmd As String = <![CDATA[
INSERT INTO devices
VALUES (
    NULL , 
    'ONE', 
    'TWO', 
    (
        SELECT manufacturer_id FROM manufacturers WHERE manufacturer_name = "Bloom"
    )
)
]]>.Value()
```

The problem is I need to brake this for using VB variables. There is another way instead of multiple CDATA's ?

```
<![CDATA[ ...... ]]>.Value() + myVBvar +  <![CDATA[ ...... ]]>.Value()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using SqlParameters

```
Dim commandString As String = <![CDATA[
  INSERT INTO blah VALUES (@One, @Two, @Three, @n)
 ]]>,Value()

Using command As SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection)
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@One", valueOne)
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Two", valueTwo) '  etc...

  '  command.execute
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm re-posting a variant of my answer from "[Multiline strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net)" because it is relevant.

You basically have to terminate the CDATA tags before the VB variable and then re-add it after so the CDATA does not capture the VB code.  You need to wrap the entire code block in a tag because you will you have multiple CDATA blocks.

```
Dim cmd As String = <sql><![CDATA[
INSERT INTO devices
VALUES (
  NULL , 
  ']]><%= varOne %><![CDATA[', 
  ']]><%= varTwo %><![CDATA[', 
  (
    SELECT manufacturer_id
    FROM manufacturers
    WHERE manufacturer_name = "]]><%= manufacturerName %><![CDATA["
  )
)
]]></sql>.value
```