# Visual Studio's horrendous colorization of CDATA XML blocks in VB.

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, editor, cdata

It really hurts the eyes.   I'm using XML Literals as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674434/614263 so that I can conveniently have many lines of SQL in my VB.NET program.   When I need sql's '<>' (not equal), I'm forced to use CDATA,  and VS colorizes those just plain horrible.  It's like a super-light grey.

Has anyone encountered this and knows how to fix it, or workaround it?

Comment: Take a look at [this site](http://studiostyl.es/) of pre-made color themes for VS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into the options and change it to the color of your choice.

`Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > show setting for - text editor.`

`VB XML CData Section`

Comment: Well, right direction, but you don't give the final answer, which settings to change.

Comment: Yep, there is a "VB XML CData Section" item.   Thanks!