# How to set a multiline string variable in vbnet

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I need to store a multiline string inside a variable:

```
dim str as string = "
    some words
    some words
    some
    words
"
```

How?

Comment: Add Environment.NewLine where you want the line break

Comment: @Steve thanks 'cause that's a solution but really I want to avoid the usage of "newlines" because I have texts of a large number of lines, I cannot set a multiline string in vbnet as C# multiline strings?

Comment: You don't want to use Environment.NewLine but want newlines in the string?

Comment: you might consider using external text file if your text is extremely large.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use the classes to insert new lines, you can do it like this:

```
Dim Logo As String= <a><![CDATA[
___  ___        _  _    _  _  _              
|  \/  |       | || |  (_)| |(_)             
| .  . | _   _ | || |_  _ | | _  _ __    ___ 
| |\/| || | | || || __|| || || || '_ \  / _ \
| |  | || |_| || || |_ | || || || | | ||  __/
\_|  |_/ \__,_||_| \__||_||_||_||_| |_| \___|


 _____  _          _                         
/  ___|| |        (_)                        
\ `--. | |_  _ __  _  _ __    __ _           
 `--. \| __|| '__|| || '_ \  / _` |          
/\__/ /| |_ | |   | || | | || (_| |          
\____/  \__||_|   |_||_| |_| \__, |          
                              __/ |          
                             |___/           
]]></a>.Value

Console.WriteLine(Logo)
```

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net has no such feature and it will **not** be coming in Visual Studio 2010.

look [Multiline strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net/706920#706920/) for workarounds

Comment: dont you mean has not come in visual studio 2010 or 2012, refering to a prduct that has been released in the future tense is slightly strange.

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this ..

```
dim str as string = "some words" & vbCrlf & "some words" & vbCrlf & "some" & vbCrlf & "words"
```

OR try it with vbLf

Answer (score 0):

you can use XML for this like

```
dim vrstr as string = <s>
    some words
    some words
    some
    words
</s>
```