# How to make a long SQL string look nice

Tags: sql, vb.net

I use the command below to run a SQL query.

```
Dim SQLString as String
da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLString, Conn)
```

Often the SQLstring is really long. I use following method:

```
SQLString = " Select *
SQLString += vbCrLf & " From"
SQLString += vbCrLf & " Student"
```

But when you debug and get SQLString in immideate window, and paste it to [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) (SSMS) Tools, it becomes one line and not formatted/indented nicely.

What's the trick for this so I can keep the string formatted nice?

Comment: Use C#. (couldn't resist).  You can use the verbatim string literal in C# .NET to go over multiple lines (even though that's not its main purpose).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net)

Comment: How about using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172824.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an XML literal in VB.NET to create your SQL statement:

```
        Dim sql = <sql>
SELECT *
    FROM Student AS S
    JOIN Class AS C
        ON S.Id = C.Id
</sql>.Value
```

Note that if you want to use the `<` or `&` symbols then you should type `&lt;` and `&amp;`, respectively, to comply with XML.

The spaces that you see in the XML are literally in the resulting string, so it wouldn't really matter if you had it formatted as

```
Dim sql = <sql>
            SELECT *
                FROM Student AS S
                JOIN Class AS C
                    ON S.Id = C.StudentId
          </sql>.Value
```

(as long as there isn't a literal string in the SQL which goes over more than one line).

I don't know who should be attributed as the first person to realise this can be done.

**UPDATE FOR VB version 14** (the one that comes with VS2015): Multi-line string literals are now implemented, so you can use

```
Dim sql = "SELECT *
From Student As S
Join Class As C
    On S.Id = C.Id"
```

Comment: Isn't instanciating an `XElement` just to work around the VB syntax a bit excessive? Also, I haven't tried but are the line breaks properly preserved? Since this is not a `CDATA` block I would guess not? The need to escape `<` is also _highly_ annoying when writing SQL.

Comment: @jods It may be excessive, but it's the computer doing the work for you. Yes, escaping `<` is annoying. TBH, I just do everything with stored procedures where possible.

Comment: Yeah... just not feeling good about referencing `System.Xml.Linq` and having all the instanciation and processing of `XElement` happening at runtime for what should just be a string constant (i.e. free).

Comment: @jods as a programmer my job is to write code so the user has a good experience.  This sometimes means me working harder so the code runs faster...

Comment: in VS2015 having this is implemented can be one of a good reason to upgrade :)

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET does not really have a clean way to do that (yet). C# has verbatim strings but AFAIK it's not in VB.

I usually do this:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * " &
          "FROM Table " &
          "WHERE x > 4 " &
          "ORDER BY 1 DESC"
```

It's not too bad to read in the code, but as you wrote it's ugly in the debugger -- all on one line. You can still copy-paste from the debugger to a SQL editor and use a code formatting feature, not great :(

**EDIT** Just in case you can code in C# rather than VB, you can do that and it's nice:

```
string sql = @"
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE x > 4
ORDER BY 1 DESC";
```

The key is the `@` before the string. Now you have nice code *and* good formatting in the debugger (line breaks are preserved).