# Tauntalizing vb.net error: XML literals and XML axis properties are not available, as a required reference was not provided

Tags: vb.net, xml-literals

So I put some code like this in my legacy vb.net  app (just upgraded from framework 2.0 to 4.0 - so missing default references):

```
    eag.stAgentXML = _
       <Agent>
         <Number><%= (CaseRoot.AgentForCase.State.PadLeft(4, "0"c) & " " & _
                   CaseRoot.AgentForCase.Number.PadLeft(4, "0"c) & "-" & _
                   CaseRoot.AgentForCase.Rank) %></Number>
         <Name><%= CaseRoot.AgentForCase.LastName & ", " & CaseRoot.AgentForCase.FirstName %></Name>
       </Agent>.Value
```

And it gives me this extremely helpful message:

```
XML literals and XML axis properties are not available, as a required reference was not provided
```

Who, on the vb.net team, can I scream at for not going the last millimeter and actually *telling me* which reference to include?

Why didn't they just tell me how they really felt, and make the error message read, "Nice try but this code is wrong. good luck."

Oh - and I would not mind knowing how to make it actually work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Add references to System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq, and System.Core.

Taken from [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531455%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)