# How to add an SQL file to resources in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql

I have a Visual Basic application. I need to add an SQL file to resources and be able to use it as an SQL file (.sql).

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: This is an annoying known issue with Visual Studio. When trying to add a new item, there are no options to create a SQL file, and the solution provided where one uses the "Existing Item" is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the following steps to add an SQL file into your project:

1. Right-click your project in Visual Studio and select *Add* → *Existing Item*
2. Then you can find the SQL file and click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button to add it into your project.
3. click the SQL file and in the properties window to set the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource"

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the **project name**. Click on *Add existing item*. Select *View all files*. Add your file. (You can add any file type to the project.)