# Conversion of Calling SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

First of all, apologies for this question. Let me write first, I've tried the below code for calling a `SOAP` web service using `C#` that worked perfectly. Now I am stuck with the conversion of the code into `VB.NET`:

```
public void CallService(string username, string password)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();
    XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();

    SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                              <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                              <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                                <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"">
                                  <wsse:UsernameToken>
                                       <wsse:Username>" + username + @"</wsse:Username>
                                       <wsse:Password>" + password + @"</wsse:Password>
                                    </wsse:UsernameToken>
                                 </wsse:Security>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Header>
                             <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                               <OTA_PingRQ xmlns=""http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"" EchoToken=""abc123"" TimeStamp=""2016-07-12T10:00:29.0Z"" Version=""1"">
                                 <EchoData> Hello World </EchoData>
                               </OTA_PingRQ>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");

     using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
     {
        SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);
     }

     ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
     using (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())
     {
         using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
         {
              var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
              lblMsg.Text = ServiceResult;
         }
     }
 }

 public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
 {
    HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://cmtpi.siteminder.com/pmsxchangev2/services/CITRUS");
    Req.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
    Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    Req.Accept = "text/xml";
    Req.Method = "POST";
    return Req;
 }
```

The above is a working code and my problem is when I try to convert it `VB.NET` and there are few errors with quotations and even the **Import** keyword (Instead of `using` in `C#`) shows error as follows: I am not that expert with `VB.NET` and would just expect some directions to make it work (Googled but unable to find the appropriate solution)

```
Public Sub CallService(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CreateSOAPWebRequest()
    Dim SOAPReqBody As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

        SOAPReqBody.LoadXml("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http:schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                              <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                                <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http:'docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"">
                                  <wsse:UsernameToken>
                                       <wsse:Username>" + username + "</wsse:Username>
                                       <wsse:Password>" + password + "</wsse:Password>
                                    </wsse:UsernameToken>
                                 </wsse:Security>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Header>
                             <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                               <OTA_PingRQ xmlns=""http:'www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"" EchoToken=""abc123"" TimeStamp=""2016-07-12T10:00:29.0Z"" Version=""1"">
                                 <EchoData> Hello World </EchoData>
                               </OTA_PingRQ>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>")

        Imports (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
    SOAPReqBody.Save(Stream)
        }

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Imports (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Imports (StreamReader rd = New StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
            {
    Dim ServiceResult As Var = rd.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(ServiceResult)

    Console.ReadLine()
            }
        }
    End Sub

Public Function CreateSOAPWebRequest() As HttpWebRequest
    Dim Req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://cmtpi.siteminder.com/pmsxchangev2/services/CITRUS"), HttpWebRequest)
    Req.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action")
        Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\""
    Req.Accept = "text/xml"
    Req.Method = "POST"
    Return Req
End Function
```

[image: Sample Code]

Comment: Did you try with a tool such as http://converter.telerik.com/ or https://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?

Comment: I've tried with the other one but failed. Will the above work?

Comment: Why not try it, it only takes a few seconds? Btw where did you get the idea that the equivalent of C#'s `using` was `Import` or `Imports` in VB.NET? AFAIK the equivalent is `Using`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/ both of your functions converted.

Comment: Tried with the above tools and worked perfectly. But it's unable to convert the quotations that I've shown in the image - Section SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(). Any idea to resolve them @ADyson?

Comment: Other than the use of & instead of + for concatenation, there's not much difference in how Strings are declared in vb and c#. You might need to join between the multiple lines of code using &_. You can easily look up all this syntax in the language documentation

Comment: Worked perfectly @ADyson and thanks a lot. You can post your comments as an answer, so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the majority of the code automatically using a tool, there are many available, but a couple of examples are http://converter.telerik.com/ or https://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/.

You may find it chokes a bit on the multi-line split string. However, it's not too hard to resolve. Other than the use of `&` instead of `+` for concatenation, there's not much difference in how Strings are declared in VB.NET and C#. You might need to join between the multiple lines of text using `_`. You can easily look up all this syntax in the language documentation if you have further issues with it.

P.S. In your manual attempt, the use of VB's `Imports` in place of C#'s `using` is incorrect. The direct equivalent in VB is simply `Using`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type for details of the two keywords in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with your VB code is that you need to indicate when a string literal is longer than one line using the underscore character and concatenation operator (&).  Example:

```
exampleliteral = _
"First few words of sentence that is longer than one line, " _
& "more words on second line, " _
& "end of sentence."
```

[MSDN documentation about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code)

[Stack Overflow question and answers about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461714/single-statement-across-multiple-lines-in-vb-net-without-the-underscore-characte)

Answer (score -1):

Use string interpolation with $ in vb as you use @ in c#

```
Dim str = $"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                              <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                              <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                                <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"">
                                  <wsse:UsernameToken>
                                       <wsse:Username>" + username + $"</wsse:Username>
                                       <wsse:Password>" + password + $"</wsse:Password>
                                    </wsse:UsernameToken>
                                 </wsse:Security>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Header>
                             <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                               <OTA_PingRQ xmlns=""http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"" EchoToken=""abc123"" TimeStamp=""2016-07-12T10:00:29.0Z"" Version=""1"">
                                 <EchoData> Hello World </EchoData>
                               </OTA_PingRQ>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                             </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```